# Function with zero average

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-space

What does it mean to have zero average? Does it mean that the integral over the whole integration domain is zero or for any symmetrical interval around $0$?

I came across the following example where $\Omega$ is a function with zero average, $x'=x/|x|$ and $\phi$ is some Schwartz function. It then says the equality comes from the fact that $\Omega$ has zero average.
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{|x|>\epsilon}\frac{\Omega(x')}{|x|^n}\phi(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{|x|<1}\frac{\Omega(x')}{|x|^n}[\phi(x)-\phi(0)]\mathrm{d}x+\int_{|x|>1}\frac{\Omega(x')}{|x|^n}\phi(x)\mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align*}

But for this to be true the integral $$\int_{|x|<1}\frac{\Omega(x')}{|x|^n}[\phi(0)]\mathrm{d}x$$ should be equal to $0$, so does this mean it has zero average on $(-1,1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice $Ω = Ω(x')$ is a function defined on the unit sphere. So what it means is that $\Omega$ has zero average on the unit sphere, i.e.
$$0=\int_{|x'|=1} \Omega(x') \,\sigma(dx').$$
This helps when you use polar coordinates to rewrite the integral over  $\epsilon<|x|<1$,
$$\int_{\epsilon<|x|<1}\frac{Ω(x') }{|x|^n} \, dx = \int_{r=\epsilon}^1 \frac{1}{r^n}r^{n-1}\underbrace{\int_{|x'|=1}Ω(x') \, \sigma(dx')}_{=0} \ dr  = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. A small question, unfortunately the book I'm reading does not really define $\Omega$ besides saying that it is a function on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$. I assume this means the codomain to be $S^{n-1}$. But is the domain $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$? This confuses me a little.

Comment: No , it specifies the domain. I would assume a function on the unit sphere is $S^{n-1} \to \mathbb R$. Some authors differentiate between functions, and fields = vector valued functions, but if it is vector valued then the integral above is to be understood componentwise in the target which reduces to the 1D codomain case.

Comment: Thank you, that was very enlightening.